# Refactoring numpy and pandas dataframe into dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I'm trying to refactor some code so that this it does not have so much repetition to it. What I'm trying to do is create an input for a multiple channel/input neural network. The features that are being considered come from two different sources completely and the inputA here is a 2D array and has to be kept in this format.

I have the following code:

```
'Create Input Values'
inputA= word_embeddings.numpy()
inputB = df['Features'].values
y = df['Target'].values

full_model_inputs = [inputA, inputB]

#Create Dictionary
original_model_inputs = dict(inputA= inputA, inputB= inputB)

'Create Train and Validation Data from Inputs'
#Preserve data dimensionality for data split
df = pd.DataFrame({"inputA":original_model_inputs["inputA"],  
                   "inputB":list(original_model_inputs["inputB"])})

#Data Split
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(df, y, test_size = 0.25)

#Convert back to original format
x_train = x_train.to_dict("list")
x_valid = x_valid.to_dict("list")

#Format dictionary items as arrays to be functional for model
x_train = {k:np.array(v) for k,v in x_train.items()}
x_valid = {k:np.array(v) for k,v in x_valid.items()}
```

Are there any suggestions to improve this code? Just want some insight from the community.

what the dictionary looks like:

```
{'inputA': array([40., 68., 46., ..., 60., 42., 50.]),
 'inputB': array([[-1.915694  , -2.39863253, -1.75456583, ...,  2.11158562,
          2.42145038,  1.0996474 ],
        [-1.99583805, -2.38059568, -1.94454968, ...,  2.14585209,
          2.56227231,  1.2808286 ],
        [-2.1607585 , -2.29914975, -1.85722673, ...,  2.04741383,
          2.34712863,  1.77104282],
        ...,
        [-2.1576829 , -2.28505015, -1.71492636, ...,  2.05909061,
          2.43704724,  1.90647388],
        [-1.81904769, -2.74457788, -2.15936947, ...,  2.31333733,
          2.50243115,  1.75907826],
        [-2.01300311, -2.32310271, -2.00470185, ...,  2.09641671,
          2.53372359,  1.22000134]])}
```

Comment: This may be a better fit in CodeReview.  While SO loves to tackle "numpy vectorization" and related optimization issues, refactoring and overall ccde organization isn't a good SO fit.  But first spend some time looking at CR requirements and typical answers.  They are pickier about code being complete and runnable.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't aware of this :) I appreciate it!